# Internet Explorer alternative for VBA automation

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I have a VBA code to navigate a webpage, read content, click buttons, fill in text etc ... This code uses internet explorer. Below I didn't copy the code but only put the main objects I am using to give you an idea:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate Url
ie.Visible = True

...

Set oBrowser = ie
oBrowser.Visible = True

...    
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

Set nodeAllDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")

Txt = nodeAllDiv.Item(0).innerText

..

HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("p").Item(nodeAllDiv.Length - 1).Click

Set listButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
listButtons.Item(0).Click


Set formDivs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")
```

The issue is that recently the webpage I am navigating is not supported by internet explorer anymore and uses Chrome or Edge, therefore I cannot use this VBA code as it is.

Is there a way I can reuse what I have written so far (reusing the same objects etc ... ) ? If possible without migrating to another framework/language

Thanks

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: I think 3LexW's answer is correct. According to your description, SeleniumBasic is the best choice, you can use it with Chrome. But you have to change your code. You can also refer to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) for code examples of SeleniumBasic.

Comment: The site is not public. I thought that Microsoft could at least make Edge useable with my code.

Comment: It's not hard to learn SeleniumBasic and you can still use VBA. Edge doesn't support the COM automation interface (InternetExplorer object) used in VBA.

Comment: I just figured I cannot install Selenium, my company does forbid anything from github to be installed

Comment: Then I think you have no other choices. You need to discuss it with your company to see if you can get the authority to download SeleniumBasic.

Answer (score 1):

`Seleniumbasic` is a web automation package for the VBA environment that you might want to take a look at.

[Github repo of Seleniumbasic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/)

Comment: Thank you, do you mean that I can't reuse the objects like created for other browsers?

Comment: The actions to locate an element is quite easy to learn  for selenium, and the documentation is well written. Unfortunately you might need some time to modify your code, but the learning and migration is not hard IMO since they are quite similar.

Comment: Seleniumbasic looks dead for 6-7 years.

Comment: @Merilix2 Unfortunately yes, the repo is not in update anymore but it could be the solution for this question since the person who raised the question would like to keep the VBA code. Otherwise, other web automation solutions are more likely to be long-term.